# Different transparency settings for different applications on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, compositing

I am using Lubuntu 20.10 and the file manager (PCManFM) looks lovely when active window transparency (in 'window effects' settings) is set below 100% (running compton).  Unfortunately this makes other applications unusable (eg. Chromium).  Is it possible to apply the window effects to only the file manager, or to restrict certain applications from using it?

Comment: In Kvantum Manager, in Configure Active theme, under 'hacks', are two options for making PCManFM-Qt transparent. First, you'd have to install it. Second, you'd have to configure it. Third, you'd have to reboot (or maybe just logout and back in again). Then, you'd see what those two options do. I've never actually tried them, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @KGIII Thank you! You recommended that to me earlier in the screenshot thread ;-)  I'll install it later/tomorrow and post an answer myself.

Comment: `pcmanfm` was the LXDE file-manager, which was last used by Lubuntu in 18.04. `pcmanfm-qt` is the more modern version of the program and is used by all releases from 18.10 onwards including 20.10.  Do you really mean `pcmanfm`?

Comment: @guiverc  Apologies, I mean pcmanfm-qt.